# How to avoid duplicated try/catch in switch case in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js

Right now my code is like this:

```
const androidChannel = "android";
const iosChannel = "ios";
const smsChannel = "sms";
const emailChannel = "email";

switch(channel) {
    case iosChannel:
        try{
            output = await apnsAdaptor.processRequest(notificationRequest)
            console.log(output);
        } catch(err) {
            console.log("IOS with err: " + err);
        } 
        break;
        
    case androidChannel:
        try{
            output = await androidAdaptor.processRequest(notificationRequest)
            console.log(output);
        } catch(err) {
            console.log("Android with err: " + err);
        }
        break;
    
    case smsChannel:
        try{
            output = await smsAdaptor.processRequest(notificationRequest)
            console.log(output);
        } catch(err) {
            console.log("Sms with err: " + err);
        }
        break;
    
    default:
        console.log("This is the defualt guy");
        break;
        
}
```

It's clear that the structures for each case are quite similar, including the handling of catched error. Since there will be more cases added, I would like to avoid repeating the try/catch structure so many times. I wonder if there's a more succinct way to write this?

**P.S. When an error is caught, I still would like to get notified which case this error is from.**

Comment: Can you not just put the switch inside the try catch, try{ ... switch stuff } catch(err) { ...

Comment: @Spangle Yeah that can be a way, but still I would like to have the error message showing me where the error is from.

Comment: The solution to long, repetitive chains of `if`-`else` or `switch`-`case` is almost always a map, object or other keyable data structure. There is some kind of false sentiment out there that `switch`-`case` is somehow cleaner than `if`-`else`. It almost always suffers from the same problem except with uglier syntax.

Comment: @isakyodo see my answer, the `switch` is inside the `try` but it still says where the error is from (when it was first posted, I forgot to change that, but it's updated now)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Make the adapters into an object indexed by channel instead, and look up the channel property on the object:

```
const adapters = {
  android: <theAndroidAdapter>,
  ios: <theIosAdapter>,
  // ...
};
// ...

const adapter = adapters[channelName];
if (adapter) {
  try {
    console.log(await adapter.processRequest(notificationRequest));
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(channelName + ' with err: ', err);
  }
} else {
  // no matching adapter
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could wrap the switch statement in try catch:

```
try {
  switch(channel) {
    case iosChannel:
        output = await apnsAdaptor.processRequest(notificationRequest)
        console.log(output);
        break;
        
    case androidChannel:
        output = await androidAdaptor.processRequest(notificationRequest)
        console.log(output);
        break;
    
    case smsChannel:
        output = await smsAdaptor.processRequest(notificationRequest)
        console.log(output);
        break;
    
    default:
        console.log("This is the defualt guy");
        break;
        
  }
} catch(err) {
    console.log(channel, " with error ", err);
}
```

Comment: Wait,  `console.log` can take multiple parameters? How did I not know that?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
try{
    switch(channel) {
        case iosChannel:
            output = await apnsAdaptor.processRequest(notificationRequest)
            console.log(output);
            break;    
    case androidChannel:
            output = await androidAdaptor.processRequest(notificationRequest)
            console.log(output);
            break;   
    case smsChannel:
            output = await smsAdaptor.processRequest(notificationRequest)
            console.log(output);
            break;   
    default:
        console.log("This is the defualt guy");
    }
} catch(err) {
    console.log(`${channel} with err: ${err}`);
}
```

Yeah, the error messages are slightly different, but hey, you do what you can do.